# How to upload zip file in the background using URLSession?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to upload an existing zip file to a local server, but the file itself doesn't seem to be present in the request when I check what the server actually receives.

Here's my current implementation:

```
func uploadZip(filePath: URL, authorization: String, callback: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {
    BGUploadManager.callback = callback
    let url = URL(string: "\(APINetwork.BASE_URL)")!
        
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer " + authorization]
    request.method = HTTPMethod(rawValue: "POST")
    request.setValue("application/zip", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "identifier")
    config.isDiscretionary = false

    let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        
    let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: filePath)
    task.resume()
}
```

There are implemented handlers for completion and progress and they work properly. The problem is really just the actual file not being sent (or if it is I don't know how to get it).

Here's parts of what the server receives:

```
headers:
   { host: 'localhost:1337',
     'content-type': 'application/zip',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     accept: '*/*',
     'user-agent': 'App/37 CFNetwork/1237 Darwin/20.4.0',
     authorization:
      'Bearer sometokenhere',
     'content-length': '89634' }
body: {}
```

Checking for `request.files` also shows that it's empty. The Content-Length value is correct. The filePath is the full path and does actually point to the zip file.

Comment: Change the header addition to: `request.setValue("compress, gzip;q=1.0, *;q=0.5", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")`

Comment: Sorry I just updated that if you read it before.

Comment: Are you sure this should be a Post request?

Comment: Why would I send data with GET?

Comment: @Jake Gives me the same result.

Comment: If you're trying to upload a zip file, you're sending data. If you're using GET that may be the problem. I would switch it to POST

Comment: Of course I'm using POST.

Comment: Why don't you use `uploadTask(with:fromFile:completionHandler:)` instead of `uploadTask(with:fromFile:)`?

Comment: How would adding a completion handler suddenly put the file into the request?

Comment: Besides completion handlers are not supported in background modes.

Comment: "How would adding a completion handler suddenly put the file into the request?"  It will help you see an error if any.

Comment: Completion handlers are not supported in background modes, and URLSession has its own handlers for completion, progress, etc. Besides the question itself points to there not being errors in the process but in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [asking on the Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/686368), investigating the problem further revealed that it was in fact a server-side issue.

Here is the answer I was given in case the above link no longer works:

> Honestly, it sounds like you have server-side problems. Some advice:
>
> - Temporarily switch to using a standard `NSURLSession` rather than a background session. That makes debugging this sort of thing much easier.
> - Use the techniques in [Debugging HTTP Server-Side Errors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/debugging_http_server-side_errors) to inspect the request and confirm that it’s in the format you expect. That’ll tell you whether you should debug this on the client side or the server side.
>
> ps If you have access to the current beta OS releases you can use the shiny new HTTP support in Instruments to debug this. 
> For more info, see WWDC 2021 Session 10212 [Analyze HTTP traffic in Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10212/).
>
> Share and Enjoy 
> — 
> Quinn “The Eskimo!” @ Developer Technical Support @ Apple 
> `let myEmail = "eskimo" + "1" + "@" + "apple.com"`

Clarification:

The server is running Node.js 
On the client, it used to be that the files would be sent as data, the old way of doing things was to simply check the request for its content (it was multipart form data).

As background URLSession uses `application/octet-stream` instead, the correct way of doing this was to add handlers as outlined in the ["Readable Streams" section of the "Streams" Node.js API documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams), that is, manually add incoming data to a buffer as data is received, and writing the content to a file on an end of stream event.

Comment: Can you say more about what the server side problem actually was?

Comment: Edited the answer to outline the server-side fix.